# Delete auto-comment when retracting a duplicate close-vote

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, automatic-comments, retracted-close-votes

I noticed that when retracting a close-vote for a duplicate, the auto-comment stays. Which then requires that extra step of having to delete it manually.

This works counter to how the comment disappears automatically when the dupe close-vote is actually closed as such.

This can lead to that extra noise you don't need to have in the comments, especially when the dupe is wrong. You do not want any reference to the incorrect dupe when retracting due to a bad close reason.

The caveat here would be that this should only happen ([as brought up by Jon Clements in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345680/delete-auto-comment-when-retracting-a-duplicate-close-vote#comment457884_345680)) when there are no up-votes on the auto-comment.

By automatically removing the auto-comment when retracting a close-vote, it will:

- Remove the human error of forgetting to manually delete the comment
- Stay aligned with the current functionality of how the comment
  disappears when a dupe is actually closed
- Allow that extra certainty
  of removing any traces of the incorrect dupe-link.

Comment: What if someone's also voted to close as a duplicate, but an auto-comment didn't get posted, as your comment was (and the system avoids posting duplicate duplicate comments)... The comment would then be lost as you'd retracted your vote until someone else then decides to vote as a duplicate. The clear up when a question is closed at least means a decision has been reached rather than someone just re-thinking...

Comment: @JonClements auto-comments raised by other voters get auto-upvotes, so I guess the system would know which people voted to close as dupe. It would be straightforward to keep the comment as long as there's at least one outstanding dupe vote that applies, i.e. only delete the comment if everyone's revoked theirs.

Comment: @Andras Well, you'd also want to cater for retracting flags as duplicates then if you want to implement reference counting... I have a gut feeling this is a lot more difficult to implement that at first thought. Also, if you're retracting your vote because you're sure it's wrong - while you're at it, why not just delete the comment and write another one saying "this isn't a duplicate of ... because..."?

Comment: @JonClements My observation is that if you are the first individual to vote a dupe, the auto-comment is posted under your name, and any subsequent dupe votes get assigned as an upvote to the auto-comment.

Comment: @JonClements right, I forgot about dupe *flags*, that does make it more complicated. But then this suggestion would be great in a large number of cases when a single voter realizes after a short while that they're wrong, so there's only one vote to begin with. When there are multiple dupe votes, odds are the duplicate is correct (because no voters on SO are ever wrong;).

Comment: @Andras I think what you've got in there is a more feasible suggestion: "If I retract my close vote and my auto comment has no upvotes - automatically delete it..."

Comment: @JonClements That is a very good point you bring up. Because if I retract my vote, other people might think that it is valid.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems unnecessary and error-prone.

For starters, there just aren't that many of these. Out of over 144 thousand duplicate *votes* that created a comment in the past 365 days, only 2595 were retracted. Out of those, only 2224 comments were never voted on, all but 469 are already deleted, and all but 178 of *those* have replies.

So this would get rid of a trivial number of comments while standing a good chance of breaking an ongoing discussion over whether the duplicate is valid or not.

Also, it would appear that folks who retract their flags are already doing a pretty good job of cleaning up after themselves (in sharp contrast to some of the other auto-comments that are generated on the site) - thus, I'd much prefer to defer to human judgement until such a time as this becomes a severe source of noise or confusion.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Those are valid points. Can't argue with stats like that. I guess my only concern in all this was just the lingering comment that would point to a *irrelevant* answer. But, bigger fish to fry and all that.

Comment: @idjaw it helps that the data is easily accessible, usually it requires a blood sacrifice.