# Should comment upvotes be automatically retracted when closevote is retracted?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, comment-votes

When you close vote a question that's already been proposed by somebody else, the act of close vote automatically upvotes that close-proposal comment.

But if you later retract the that close vote, that auto-upvote on that comment isn't removed/retracted.

Should this be considered as a bug and the comment upvote be retracted automatically?

Comment: the auto vote (and auto comment) should simply not occur.

Comment: @KevinB That auto upvote appears to be deliberate (by design): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358813/1275169

Comment: Yes, i am aware, :) I'm simply of the opinion that if the system has a message it should share, it should do so rather than using our name/likeness to share it. It's a poor example of what comments are meant for.

Comment: I see. I thought you meant it doesn't happen at all ;-) Yeah, if auto upvote doesn't happen in the first place, this question doesn't arise.

Comment: I don't feel that strongly about it - the system may use it to signal "hey, one other guy agrees with this upe proposal". In any case, it seems logical to me that when I retract my close vote, that signal is no longer true/valid. This is not a massive issue admittedly - thought I'd ask explicitly.

Comment: Related: [Delete auto-comment when retracting a duplicate close-vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345680/8967612).

Answer (score -2):

Two schools of thought on this, but neither in favor of this feature request:

1. **Be more judicious with your duplicate close votes.**  If you are not sure if it's a duplicate, then don't just vote with the crowd and do so.
2. **The vote adds no value, and is deleted when the question is closed.**  This...is kinda self-explanatory, and I don't know the rules behind expiring close votes or anything like that, but it's safe to assume that the comment will gently fade into nothingness after a period of time *anyway*, so worrying about whether or not the vote still exists is a waste of time.

Comment: (1) feels a bit condescending. I am not sure what suggests that close votes aren't already used judiciously or people just join the "crowd". The very reason retraction exists/allowed is that when you change your mind or made a mistake, you *can* retract it. (2) makes sense as the comment will disappear *if* it's closed. Otherwise, that comment just stays as a comment forever (even if close votes expire) from what I can tell. So this is a less-common situation and obviously a low priority one. But I don't see if anything could become worse if this is implemented.

Comment: Part of the appeal of public dupe-vote comments is that OPs can clarify why their question is *not* a duplicate. There's a reason the dupe-vote comment is a *question to the OP*, not a statement.